# How do I fix this annoying Chrome for macOS scroll bar issue?

Tags: high-sierra, google-chrome, macos

Sometimes when I navigate code-formatted text that is long enough to have scroll bars, the bar doesn't disappear after I've finished scrolling and stays stuck inside the block of code, obscuring it.

Is there a way to get rid of this for good? Sometimes refreshing the page works but not all times.

Here's a block of text formatted as code if you want to give it a shot.

```
this is a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong block of pre-formatted text
```

Here's what it looks like when it happens:

[image: annoying Chrome scroll-bar issue]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to system settings > general > show scroll bars > always.